# Apply the filter condition using the json data

Tags: json, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am generating the JSON data using the UI and that UI is used to take the input from user and generate the JSON file consisting of the input. Then we use JSON file data to filter out the records on the basis of two columns(`country` and `currency`).

```
json__data = {
"Year": 2019,
"EXCHANGE":
    [
        {
            "total": 142250.0,
            "COUNTRY":"JPN",
            "CUR": "YEN"
        },
        {
            "total": 210.88999999999996,
            "COUNTRY": "US"
            "CUR": "DOL"
        },
        {
            "total": 1065600.0,
            "COUNTRY": "UK" 
            "CUR": "POU"
        }
]
```

}

Above is the json file sample. I have another file `demo.csv` that has multiple columns like(`Name`, `Currency`, `Contact_details`, `Currency` etc.). I need only the records which are containing in the json file. For example- I need records from country (`US`, `UK`, `JPN`) and currency(`DOL`, `POU`, `YEN`). I need the logic to implement this condition.

```
import json
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, json__data,a):
         self.a = []
         self.dict = json.loads(json__data)
          for data in dict:
               a.append(data['COUNTRY'])          #a= [US, UK, JPN] 
               b.append(data['CUR'])              #b= [DOL, POU, YEN]
        
def spark(self,a):
     ss = SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]").appName("This is sample csv").getOrCreate()
     df = ss.read.format("csv").load("C:\\Users\\demo.csv")
     dt = spark.sql(SELECT * FROM df where col("COUNTRY") IN a  and col("CURRENCY") IN b)  # I need all records satisfying given filter conditions
     ds = dt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `filter` like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1 = df.filter(F.col("COUNTRY").isin(a) & F.col("CURRENCY").isin(b))
```

Or you can read the json file using spark then join with the other dataframe from csv:

```
df_json = spark.read.json("path_to_json")
df_csv = spark.read.csv("path_to_csv")

result = df_csv.join(
    df_json.select("COUNTRY", "CURRENCY"),
    on=["COUNTRY", "CURRENCY"],
    how="inner"
)
```